# Embedding with vanishing images of homotopy groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $f$ be a locally flat embedding from $S^2 \times \mathbb R^2$ to $S^2 \times \mathbb R^2$ such that $f_*(\pi_k(S^2 \times \mathbb R^2))=0$ for any $k \ge 2$.

Can we find a domain $U$ that contains the image of $f$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: In this situation, if $f_*=0$ on $\pi_2$ then $f$ is nullhomotopic (and therefore $f_*=0$ on $\pi_k$ for all $k$).